# почему #1215 - Невозможно добавить ограничения внешнего ключа?

Tags: mysql

```
на локальном нет никаких проблем
```

когда выгружал БД на сервер пишет для таблицы

```
SQL запрос:


CREATE TABLE `permission_role` (
  `permission_id` bigint unsigned NOT NULL,
  `role_id` bigint unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`permission_id`,`role_id`),
  KEY `permission_role_role_id_foreign` (`role_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `permission_role_permission_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`permission_id`) REFERENCES `permissions` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `permission_role_role_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`role_id`) REFERENCES `roles` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
Ответ MySQL: Документация

#1215 - Невозможно добавить ограничения внешнего ключа
```

Comment: Таблицы, на которые ссылаетесь в внешних ключах, существуют в новой базе?

Comment: файл я только начал заливать и сразу ошибка т.е они вставится не успели

Comment: при заливке отклбючил проверку внешних ключей тогда без ошибок так же можно?